# How to add Django after installing Python 3.6 in whm via ssh?

Tags: django, python-3.x, cpanel, whm

I have a VPS and it does not provide a one-click Python Installation as some other VPS services do. After many failed attempts I finally installed Python 3.6.3 via my WHM ssh.

Can someone guide me on how to set up Django next and proceed to development?

Comment: What is WHM? Why can't you install it normally with pip?

Comment: And why are you trying to development on a remote VPS anyway? Develop locally, then deploy to your host.

Comment: @DanielRoseman eventually we had to do that. We installed everything via SSH.
WHM is web host manager. A GUI tool to manage your server. Some VPS companies provide a module that allows you to install Python and Django in a particular section of your regular PHP site. But our VPS did not have that option. Hence my question.